# How would I replace a "TAB" in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I'm attempting to format a giant list. Each entry in the list is separated by a tab. I'd like to replace it with a \r\n in Notepad++.

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 50):

Find what:

```
\t
```

Replace with:

```
\r\n
```

For `Search Mode`, I think you have to select Extended (\n, \r, \t, \0, \x...).